# Parser catch-all parameter list

Tags: c#, sql, antlr4

Ok, I've lost two days on this, and looked at every other answer having to do with ANTLR4 on Stack, but I can't resolve this.

I'm parsing a SQL table definition that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GeographicZones](
    [GeographicZoneID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Township] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Range] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Section] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [TownshipRange]  AS ((((('T'+CONVERT([varchar](3),[Township],0))+case when [Township]>(0) then 'N' else 'S' end)+'R')+CONVERT([varchar](3),[Range],0))+case when [Range]>(0) then 'E' else 'W' end),
    [LAOZone] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [MSDZone] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ParrottZone] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_GeographicZones] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [GeographicZoneID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UK_GeographicZones_TRS] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Township] ASC,
    [Range] ASC,
    [Section] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The key bit that I can't resolve is that `TownshipRange` computed column. I don't care about the contents between `()` after the `AS` statement, and want to ignore up to the comma delimiter.

Here is the `computedColumn` rule:

```
/**
TSql only. In code generation, this is mapped as a read-only
property. In translation, special comments are placed that
indicate that this should be a computed column.
*/
computedColumn
    : columnName AS anyExpr ( PERSISTED ( NOT NULL )? )?
    {
    logInfo( "Computed column {0}",
        $columnName.ctx.GetText() );
    }
    ;
```

Here is the `anyExpr` rule, which used to work in ANTLR4 4.0.1:

```
/**
Use for a parameter list (blah blah) where we don't care
about the contents. Uses a sempred to go until $open == 0.
Note that the right paren is missing from the end of the rule -
this is by design.
*/
anyExpr
locals [int open = 1]
    : Lp
    ( {$open > 0}? 
        ( ~( Lp | Rp )
        | Lp { $open++; }
        | Rp { $open--; }
        )
    )*
    ;
```

Here is the logged output using ANTLR4 4.3.0:

```
INFO    Computed column [TownshipRange]
line 579:22 extraneous input '(' expecting {Comma, Rp}
```

That `(` that it's failing on is the first nested left paren. But it fails immediately with the same warning no matter what the first character after the opening paren.

What is wrong with my "catch-all" logic, and what changed between 4.0.1 and 4.3 that would break this?

As a side note (it may have something to do with the problem) 4.3 takes AGES to parse the entire SQL file in LL mode, so I'm using SLL. 4.0.1 recognizes the rule in both LL and SLL and there is very little difference in parse times.

Is 4.0.1 possibly just ignoring the extraneous input and my `anyExpr` has been broken all along?

Comment: Why not reference `anyExpr` in itself? `anyExpr : Lp ( ~( Lp | Rp ) | anyExpr )* Rp ;`

Comment: Good Lord Bart that may have just worked. I'll let you know. Could you post as the answer once I do? I tend to overcomplicate things.

Comment: Bart you are the man. 100,000 lines of C# code in about a second or so, using SLL or LLExact!! I've learned my lesson - go to Stack first! :)

Comment: :) Cool, then I put it down as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not reference anyExpr in itself?

```
anyExpr
 : Lp ( ~( Lp | Rp ) | anyExpr )* Rp 
 ;
```

And this may result in a quicker parse (didn't try it myself!):

```
anyExpr
 : Lp ( ~( Lp | Rp )+ | anyExpr )* Rp 
 ;
```

Comment: Thanks again. So simple, so elegant.